# Android USB actions(ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED & ACTION_USB_DEVICE_DETACHED) not working in BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, android-broadcastreceiver, android-usb

I'm working on a App which has a requirement to listen on USB events (ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED & ACTION_USB_DEVICE_DETACHED). I have created a receiver which listens on the these actions. But my receiver is not firing up when any of these events occur.

Android Manifest :

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.usb.host" />

<receiver android:name=".USBEventReceiver">
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_STATE"/>
                <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED"/>
                <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_DETACHED"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED"
                android:resource="@xml/usb_device"/>
            <meta-data android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_DETACHED"
                android:resource="@xml/usb_device"/>
 </receiver>
```

BroadCastReceiver onReceive method :

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        UsbDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE);
        UsbManager usbManager = (UsbManager)context.getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);

        if (intent.getExtras().getBoolean("connected")) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onReceive: connected");
        } else if (!intent.getExtras().getBoolean("connected")) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onReceive: disconnected");
        }

        if (usbManager != null) Log.d(TAG, "onReceive: " + usbManager.getDeviceList().toString());

        if (device != null) Log.d(TAG, "USB Attached: " + device);


        if (UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED.equals(action)) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onReceive: " + device.getManufacturerName());
            Log.d(TAG, "onReceive: " + device.getProductName());
            Log.d(TAG, "onReceive: " + device.getSerialNumber());
            Log.d(TAG, "onReceive: " + device.getSerialNumber());
        } else if (UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_DETACHED.equals(action)) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onReceive: " + device.getManufacturerName());
            Log.d(TAG, "onReceive: " + device.getProductName());
            Log.d(TAG, "onReceive: " + device.getSerialNumber());
        }

    }
```

Comment: Did you get the solution to this ?

Comment: @RohitMat Yes i did get one.

Answer (score 3):

This question is old but I'll still take a stab at it. In order to have something take action on these USB commands, I used a BroadCast Receiver. 
```

```
private final Broadcast Receiver mUsbReceiver = 
    switch(intent.getAction() {
        case UsbService.ACTION_USB_ATTACHED:
           //do something
        case UsbService.ACTION_USB_DETACHED:
            //do something
```

```

Where you need to register your receiver with something like:

```
private void setFilters() {
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();

    //New Service Filters
    filter.addAction(UsbService.ACTION_USB_ATTACHED);
    filter.addAction(UsbService.ACTION_USB_DETACHED);    
    registerReceiver(mUsbReceiver, filter);
}
```